# Move newly created text files to a var created directory

Tags: bash

I have several text docs that are created each day from templates. This process I've achieved successfully albeit probably in a Cro-Magnon way. I want these newly created text files to be filed within a *newly created* dated folder.

The script creates the file docs from the templates successfully and also creates the newly dated directory. I don't really want to create these text files somewhere else and then move them to the newly created directory. Rather that they be created directly within it. All my research tends to involve directories that already exist rather than one created from a var.

I've included just one file creation example below.

Hope you can help. TIA

```
today=`date '+%y%m%d'`;
today_Folder=~/Desktop/test/"${today}"

if [[ ! -d $today_Folder ]]
 then
   mkdir "${today_Folder} `(date '+%A')`"
fi

cat ~/Desktop/test/template.txt >> ~/Desktop/test/dest.txt
```

P.S. I've tried to make the `cat` command regarding the text files clearer - it simply creates files. I'm NOT trying to create a tree of directories. Simply ONE newly created directory that could be in *test* along with the text files.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the cat statement supposed to be moving the already created file docs to the newly created directory?  Or is it your "the script creates the file docs"?

Comment: No, the `cat` is making the text files. 

I want the text files to exist within the newly created folder. I have 6 text files that need to exist within a folder with the day's date, each and every day.

This is the problem - that folder needs to be created as a var so the date can be inserted in it. Then how do you target that newly created folder (via a variable) as the destination that these docs will be created in?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to dynamically create a file, also creating all the path to contain that file? That's not possible in any intuitive/portable way, and it's not typically programs always have to create the directory before the file. What you can do is pass the `-p` flag to `mkdir`. On Linux systems (this may also not be portable), this flag means "create all the directories necessary for this path". Zero directories is okay, so you don't need to check whether the directory already exists. So change the whole `if` block to just this:

```
mkdir -p "${today_Folder} `(date '+%A')`"
```

Also, it's kind of smelly the way you want a string (the path) and you're using three operations to create it. Could it be simpler? You want more statements when they add clarity, but in this case the steps are so simple that the only thing accomplished is to make your colleagues go up and read what you wrote more than once. It might suit to change it to:

```
dir_path=...
mkdir -p "${dir_path}"
```

To accomplish this, keep in mind that instead of backticks, you can add command substitution with `$()`. It helps since backticks can't be nested--it makes the line more readable, since you clearly see the command's start/end.

Comment: I've created this process successfully using Automator (osX) but Automator simply copies the original Template files so I have to readjust their creation dates to reflect the current day's date. Yes, I'm sure the IF statement is odorous but that's because I've got zero experience with bash scripting :-)

I used it because if the script was run accidentally and *today's* dir had already been created, the IF would cancel the process. It works. It seems that choosing a newly created directory as a destination for newly created files is difficult to do with bash.

Comment: @gazzasanx "Difficult" may have been an understatement. You just can't. The more I think about this, the more confident I am that the filesystem just won't let you create a file and a directory in the same operation. Any framework that pretends to do this will just be hiding the details. So as you progress to lower-level programming methods, you have to do more of this manual work yourself.